# Binarytree with two nodes as root?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I understand that binary tree allows only one node as its root. I am looking for data structure which allows two nodes as 1st level without root. Can we do accomplish this graph?

I have data like the following

EmpoyeeId   SupervisorId                   DeptName
1000            -1                  Business
2000            -1                  Research
1001            1000                Accouns
1002            1000                Tax2
2001            2000                Computers
1003            1001                Corp Tax
2002            2001                Operating System
1008            1001                another Tax
1009            1001                big business Tax

Given above data , how do we model this? Which data structure i should use to get employee at nth level?

Comment: Consider providing your thoughts with description why you decided to abandon them. In this form it is hard to believe that there is no unspoken requirements.

Comment: Making use of a [Btree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) perhaps?

Comment: And the reason for such a data structure?

Answer (score 2):

Having two binary trees is actually your structure.

Also you always can make virtual root node that will have no meaningful value but will point to two neighbours.